# Why can't raw types have methods with generic return types

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Consider the following class

```
class Foo<T> {
    List<String> bar() { return null; }
}
```

If I make a raw instance like this:

```
final Foo foo = new Foo();
```

I would still expect `foo.bar()` to return a `List<String>`. since the signature of `bar` is independent from `T`. However, if I do this:

```
final List<String> strings = foo.bar();
```

I get an unchecked assignment

> Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.List' to 'java.util.List'. Reason: 'foo' has raw type, so result of bar is erased.

I understand that it says `foo` is erased, but why does the erasure of `foo` also erase `List<String>` to `List`?

Currently I'm suppressing this warning with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` as it seems pointless to me.

Comment: Welcome to Java generics.

Comment: Dont call it "typeless/erased". The word that everybody knows is **raw** type ;-) ... inventing your own words only confuses readers. And yes, in essence, the answer is: dont use raw types.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot how to call it and edited the question now accordingly. And also thanks for adding the second link to the already-answered-block

Comment: Haha :) Felk, I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655504/java-generics-why-incompatible-types-compilation-error-if-a-class-generic-t) less than an hour before you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in other answers, using a "raw" class loses *all* generics, not just the class defined ones. A workaround for this is to just use a wildcard, which then doesn't care about the type but preserves generics:

```
final Foo<?> foo = new Foo<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The specification for "rare" types is already far too complicated. It would be pointless to add additional complexity for a pointless case.

Just use generics correctly with no raw types.

Comment: Is "_"rare"_ types" an intentional typo?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No. It refers to a partially raw type.