# Java generics - Why "incompatible types" compilation error if a class' generic type doesn't exist in an invoked method?

Tags: java, class, generics, compiler-errors, generic-method

Please notice the code below doesn't compile, failing on the method result assignment: `String s = a.method("abc");`.

The compilation error: `incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String`

But, when changing `A a` to `A<?> a` or to `A<Object> a`, the compilation passes.

* Please notice that the type `<T>` in the method is different than the type `<O>` in the class.

Any idea what the compilation error? Also, why the generic definition in variable `a` solves the compilation issue?

```
class A<O>
{
    O something;

    <T> T method(T t)
    {
        return t;
    }

    static void testJavaStrangeGenericDefinitionBehavior()
    {
        A a = null;

        String s = a.method("abc");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is similar to the "raw type" question. I agree that the subject of "raw types" might be the answer to this question. Similar answers don't mean the questions are duplicate.

Comment: @Makoto Not really a duplicate. Is it?

Comment: @nullpointer Yes, it is, although quite hidden in the answer of that question: *Type erasure also maps the signature of a constructor or method to a signature that has no parameterized types or type variables.*

Comment: @nullpointer:  It is *very* much a duplicate.  This is a classic raw type erasure problem, and there is a very detailed and complete answer in that dupe.

Comment: Makato, why do you think a very relevant and great **answer** means a duplicate **question**?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka:  The answer in that other question answers your question succinctly.  I do not wish to elaborate much further on this.

Answer (score -1):

```
A a = null;
```

should be:

```
A<String> a = null; // or better yet, new A<String>();
```

Although, you could substitute any class for `String` since, as you say, the `T` and `O` generics are different types.

Once you remove the generic parameter, you lose all the generics in your method call, which essentially becomes equivalent to calling:

```
Object method(Object t);
```

Comment: But if I change to `A<Object>`, it compiles as well. Please notice that the type in the method is different than the type in the class.

Comment: So you are saying that the Java compiler treats the static type `T` as `Object` only because the `a` uses a raw type? Indeed a little strange behaviour.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka As I mentioned, you can substitute any class for the `String`, such as `Object`. But you need to specify something for the generic type, otherwise you're dealing with raw types all the way through.

Comment: I think you could point that out in your answer a little more clear.

Comment: See the linked duplicate that @Makoto posted.

Comment: GD, I think the key in your answer is "Once you remove the generic parameter, you lose all the generics in your method call", Can you explain it a bit more in the answer?

Comment: GD, after removing `<O>` from the class definition, the method call line now compiles, so I'm not sure all generics are lost.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka Well, sure, once you remove the <O> you don't need to instantiate an `A` with a generic type parameter, and the method call can then remain generic (with its `<T>`) in its own right. Since this question has been marked as a duplicate, I'm not going to expand my answer.

Answer (score -2):

It's because Java's `type erasure` meaning for backward compatibility all generic type declarations exist only in source code and after compilation they are converted to `Object` references and proper casts behind the scenes so the `JVM` in this case is confused that you meant `O` or `T`.

Comment: But the error is **before** or **at** compilation. With that reasoning, Generics would not make any sense at all.

Comment: It's because compiler cannot safely do `type erasure` and so complains about it.

Comment: Where is that complaint? Obviously, the compiler does the type erasure (according to GriffeyDog's answer) very well here.